# 3rd person camera follower in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

I try to make a 3rd person camera, which follows my player and the camera should rotate, but not the player, if I use the right analog Stick of my controller. I followed this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/unity3d-third-person-cameras--mobile-11230)

My code:

```
void adjustCameraToPlayer() 
{
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.identity;
    if (Input.GetAxis("RightStickX") != 0f)
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("RightStickX") / 100f;
        transform.Rotate(0, horizontal, 0);
        float desiredAngle = transform.eulerAngles.y;
        rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, desiredAngle, 0);
    }

    transform.position = player.transform.position-(rotation * offset);

    transform.LookAt(player.transform);
}
```

My problem is that the camera rotates way too fast, I tried to change the dividend of the horizontal value but it did not help.

Answer (score 2):

That's why you always should incorporate `deltaTime` into transform operations that happen every frame. That way you aren't rotating it at magnitude every single frame, but instead over time. Also you should incorporate a `speed` variable which can be manipulated in real time, so you can tweak it just how you want:

```
public float speed = 5f;

void adjustCameraToPlayer() 
{
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.identity;
    if (Input.GetAxis("RightStickX") != 0f)
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("RightStickX");
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * horizontal * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        float desiredAngle = transform.eulerAngles.y;
        rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, desiredAngle, 0);
    }

    transform.position = player.transform.position-(rotation * offset);

    transform.LookAt(player.transform);
}
```